# Can you prevent a module from being disabled?

Tags: 7, installation

Is there any way to prevent Admins from disabling a module. Is there anything that can be done via code?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a per-module solution, add the [required](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#required) property to its .info file.

> As of version 7.x, modules and themes may specify that they are absolutely required and should never be disabled by adding required = TRUE. These modules will be enabled automatically during install. In most cases it should only be used with the Drupal core required modules (e.g. Node, User, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

No code is necessary to do this. You can setup appropriate permissions for your "admins". Create a new role for these individuals that gives them all the rights they need minus the "Administer modules" under "System".